# Pandas dataframes won't join, return key errors

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to join two Pandas dataframes, one called `data` containting some video usage data, and one called `assetids` containing the metadata for videos being viewed.  Both dataframes include a column called `['Asset ID']` with the ID numbers in the exact same format, and I confirmed with a spot check that the IDs in `data` also exist in the metadata.  The only difference is that `data['Asset ID'].dtype` is an object, while `assetids['Asset ID'].dtype` is a non-null object.

Yet, neither joins nor merges work properly.  Among the options I tried:

```
data2 = data.join(assetids, on = 'Asset ID')
```

^ Results in a blank dataframe.

```
data2 = data.join(assetids, how = 'left', on = 'Asset ID')
```

^ Results in the a half-filled dataframe

```
data2 = pd.merge(data, assetids, how='left',left_on='Asset ID', right_on= 'Asset ID')
```

^ Results in a key error on—oddly enough—`'Asset ID'`

Why won't these two dataframes merge, and how can I get them to merge?

Answer (score 0):

The tipoff for me was when I explicitly tried to run `assetids['Asset ID'].dtype`, and it returned a key error.  I still don't know exactly why the column wasn't registering (I looked for hidden characters, weird encoding, everything).

What ended up working was referencing the columns by their position in the dataframe's column list like this:

```
data2 = pd.merge(data, assetids, how='left',left_on='Asset ID', right_on=assetids.columns[0])
```

Comment: What is `assetids.columns[0]` and `type(assetids.columns[0])`?

Comment: `assetids.columns[0]` was the column I was trying to join on, `Asset ID`.  The type of that column was "non-null object", while the corresponding column in `data` was just "object".

Comment: `non-null object` refers to the data type of the *values* in the column. `type(assetids.columns[0])` will tell you Python type of the column label itself. If it is something unusual, such as a `BeautifulSoup.NavigableString`, then that would explain the odd behavior you are seeing. That is, the mystery would be explained if the two objects, `data.columns[i]` and `assetids.columns[0]` look like strings *when printed*, but compare differently: `data.columns[i] != assetids.columns[0]`

Comment: Okay, I see what you're asking.  

`type(assetids.columns[0])` is  `str`, as is `type(data.columns[0])`.  Meanwhile, both `type(assetids['Asset ID'])` and `type(data['Asset ID'])` are `pandas.core.series.Series`.  So theoretically, it still should have linked up correctly, but somehow refused to.

It was a good learning experience to know I could fall back on the direct column reference as a means of joining, though.

Comment: What is `repr(assetids.columns[0])`? Perhaps it is a string which includes a stray space or something.